# Flask multidict mapping causing error

Tags: python, flask, terminal

I'm sending a POST request via terminal to my flask backend server by doing the following:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{“Email”:”email@email.com”,”Password”:”testpass”}'  http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login
```

I can print out the request data in flask by doing the following:

```
print(request.data)
```

However, when I try to input the data into a form to validate the information, the process comes to a halt and fails.

I'm pretty sure the issue is caused by this code, since nothing gets executed after this line:

```
data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Set `debug=True` and you won't have to guess the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your quotes are all the same in your curl command. I tried adapting that to one of my apis and it returned an error. Are you using the right quotes in your json? Are those smart quotes? I was able to replace them and it worked.

`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"email@email.com","password":"testpass"}'  http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login`

If you are then taking the dictionary and then loading them into a form (`form = LoginForm(**data)`) you also need to make sure your keys match the naming of your form. I see in your json you have `Email` with E uppercase. Make sure that is the name of the form field in your form. If it is `email = StringField(...)` it won't map.

Comment: My email field is: email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required()])  I should be using a capital E, right?

Comment: Yes, or change the request to be {'email': 'email@email'}. You could also iterate over the keys and make them all lowercase. Whatever you think is best. I posted the following codeshare, it works: http://codeshare.io/At2zx

Comment: I tried using the curl request you provided, but the request doesn't go through to the flask server.  It jumps to the next line and waits for an input...

Comment: I can see it print the email but not the password.  I get the following error regarding the password `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ‘”password”`

Comment: I've found that happens if there is a quote or something off. The command works for me on osx.

Comment: ok, I edited the curl command. I took your exact command and changed the quotes being used inside the JSON. The flask app I'm running seems to like it.

Comment: You were right.  I was copying the quotes directly from SO, but they weren't right.  I didn't know what you referring to the actual quotes, I thought you meant the content within the quotes were wrong.  Thank you!